# Angular Material で theme.dark() を効かせたい

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

以下を参考に、
背景やボタンが暗くなるのかな？と思い、試してみました。

> Angular Material / Theming
> Configuring a Theme
> Specifying Dark Themes
> https://goo.gl/W2SvuR
> --
> You can mark a theme as dark by calling theme.dark().

結果、なってないのですが、

1. theme.dark() では、そもそも何が暗くなるのでしょう？
2. そして、どうすれば暗くなるのでしょう？

CodePen で試していますので、ご確認下さい。

> CodePen
> http://goo.gl/6I1ANC

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('appCtrl', function($scope) {})

  .config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
      .dark();
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">A</md-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

枠線や段落の背景を暗くする定義ですので、

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <md-content>
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary">A</md-button>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

のように、`<md-content>`などで囲むと適用されます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、確認できました。

「[Theming / Under the Hood](https://goo.gl/rKGltU)」 によると、<style> を動的に作成しているそうなので、css がどうやって効いてるか納得できました。

でも、<md-content> じゃないと効かないって、ドキュメントの何処に書かれてたんでしょう？